# Getting the entries from a Kafka topic?

Tags: java, json, apache-kafka

I have already implemented two services with databases who have to communicate via Kafka cluster.
I've already set up the first one to send his entries from the POST method in a topic with KafkaTemplate<String,User>.
I am seeing in the terminal that the entries are going into the topic.
How can I get them and produce back into POJOs or DB entries from the Kafka topic?

I've implemented a @KafkaListener in the 1st service like this, but doesnt works:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "USERS",groupId = "group_id")
public void listen(User user){
    secondService.save(user);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked, guys!

```
User user = new ObjectMapper().readValue(message,User.class);
    cachingService.save(user);
```

Comment: 1) Don't create a new ObjectMapper per record, move it to a field. 2) What type of object is `message`? You don't need to do this if you properly defined a deserializer - refer Spring Kafka docs on JSON deserialization

Comment: @OneCricketeer it's a String. this message is coming from the KafkaListener

Comment: In the question, your Kafkalistener parameter is a User object, though, which will work if you defined a Deserializer for it